# Can't detect scanner Brother DCP-195C

Tags: release-hera, software-installation, hardware, printer

I can't detect my brother DCP-195C printer. When I do a `sudo brsaneconfig3 -d` the printer appears in the list. But `scanimage -L` doesn't detect it. Please help. I'm very tired.

It's connected via USB most guides are for network printers
Tried guides from the following links, nothing worked:

1. [Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 16.04 though driver installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/brother-scanner-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed)
2. [How to detect a Brother scanner connected via USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048816/how-to-detect-a-brother-scanner-connected-via-usb)

Doing a

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i Brother
```

Results to

```
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                    1.0.0-1                                          all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                0.3.1-1                                          amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan3                                    0.2.13-1                                         amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  dcp195ccupswrapper:i386                    1.1.3-1                                          i386         Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  dcp195clpr:i386                            1.1.3-1                                          i386         Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     4-1                                              amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4.2-3                                          amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Then doing a

```
$ sudo brsaneconfig3 -d
```

Results to

```
-----------------------------
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fc8eb79b-06b7-483b-9acb-6a41dd6dbb75 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=B417-4B70  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
-----------------------------
sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x138a, product=0x0017) at libusb:001:006
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9 [Brother], product=0x0222 [DCP-195C]) at libusb:001:008
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
-----------------------------
ls -R -all /proc/bus/usb
ls: cannot access '/proc/bus/usb': No such file or directory
-----------------------------
cat /proc/bus/usb/devices
cat: /proc/bus/usb/devices: No such file or directory
-----------------------------
scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/brsanenetdevice3.cfg:

-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/Brsane3.ini:
[Support Model]


0x0206,14,2,"DCP-145C"
0x0204,14,2,"DCP-165C"
0x0205,13,2,"DCP-185C"
0x0201,14,2,"DCP-385C"
0x0200,14,2,"DCP-585CW"
0x01ff,13,2,"DCP-535CN"
0x01fe,14,1,"MFC-250C"
0x01fd,13,1,"MFC-290C"
0x01fb,13,1,"MFC-490CW"
0x01fa,13,1,"MFC-490CN"
0x01f9,13,1,"MFC-790CW"
0x01f8,13,1,"MFC-990CW"
0x01f7,14,1,"MFC-670CD"
0x01f6,13,1,"MFC-930CDN"
0x01f5,13,1,"MFC-5490CN"
0x01f4,13,1,"MFC-5890CN"
0x01f1,13,2,"DCP-6690CW"
0x01f3,13,1,"MFC-6490CW"
0x01f2,13,1,"MFC-6490CN"

0x01f0,13,1,"MFC-6890CDW"
0x01ef,13,1,"MFC-6890CN"

0x0207,14,2,"DCP-163C"
0x0208,14,2,"DCP-167C"
0x0203,14,2,"DCP-383C"
0x0202,14,2,"DCP-387C"
0x01fc,13,1,"MFC-297C"

0x01ee,1,1,"MFC-7450",131,4
0x01ed,1,1,"MFC-7840N",131,4
0x01eb,1,1,"MFC-7320",131,4
0x01ea,2,2,"DCP-7030",131,4
0x01e9,1,2,"DCP-7040",131,4
0x01e8,1,2,"DCP-7045N",131,4
0x01e7,1,1,"MFC-7340",131,4
0x01e6,1,1,"MFC-7440N",131,4
0x01e5,1,1,"MFC-7840W",131,4
    


0x0218,17,1,"DCP-8080DN",133,4
0x021f,117,1,"DCP-8085DN",133,4


0x0217,17,1,"MFC-8480DN",133,4

0x0215,117,1,"MFC-8890DW",133,4





[ModelTypeName]
1=MFC Scanner
2=DCP Scanner

[Driver]
scanfast24=0
NoUseCM=0
compression=1
Inqueue=32000
LogFile=0
xshift_c=0


-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/models3/ext2.ini:
[Support Model]

0x23e,14,2,"DCP-197C"
0x235,14,2,"DCP-377CW"
0x23a,14,1,"MFC-257CW"

-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/models3/ext1.ini:
[Support Model]

0x0222,14,2,"DCP-195C"

0x0223,14,2,"DCP-365CN"
0x0224,14,2,"DCP-375CW"
0x0225,14,2,"DCP-395CN"

0x0229,13,1,"MFC-295CN"
0x022a,13,1,"MFC-495CW"
0x022c,13,1,"MFC-795CW"
0x0228,14,1,"MFC-255CW"
0x0236,14,2,"DCP-390CN"
0x0227,13,2,"DCP-595CN"
0x022b,13,1,"MFC-495CN"
0x022d,14,1,"MFC-675CD"
0x022e,14,1,"MFC-695CDN"
0x022f,14,1,"MFC-735CD"
0x0230,13,1,"MFC-935CDN"

0x021b,17,2,"DCP-8070D",133,4
0x021a,17,1,"MFC-8370DN",133,4
0x0219,117,1,"MFC-8380DN",133,4
0x023f,117,1,"MFC-8680DN",133,4

0x0216,117,1,"MFC-8880DN",133,4


0x021d,17,1,"MFC-9120CN"
0x021c,17,1,"MFC-9320CW"
0x0220,17,1,"MFC-9010CN"
0x021e,17,2,"DCP-9010CN"

-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/models3/ext5.ini:
[Support Model]

0x0258,13,2,"DCP-J715N"
0x025e,13,1,"MFC-J615N"
0x0256,14,2,"DCP-J515N"


0x240,13,1,"MFC-J950DN"
0x25f,14,1,"MFC-J700D"
0x260,14,1,"MFC-J800D"
0x261,14,1,"MFC-J850DN"

0x0278,13,1,"MFC-J410W"
0x026f,14,1,"MFC-J270W"
0x026e,14,1,"MFC-J855DN"
0x026d,14,1,"MFC-J805D"

0x234,14,2,"DCP-373CW"
0x239,14,1,"MFC-253CW"
0x253,14,2,"DCP-J125"
0x255,14,2,"DCP-J515W"
0x259,14,1,"MFC-J220"
0x25a,13,1,"MFC-J410"
0x25c,13,1,"MFC-J415W"


0x0276,13,1,"MFC-5895CW"
-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/models3/ext3.ini:
[Support Model]
0x01c9,  17,2,"DCP-9040CN",133,4
0x01ca,  17,1,"MFC-9440CN",133,4
0x01cb, 117,2,"DCP-9045CDN",133,4
0x01cc, 117,1,"MFC-9840CDW",133,4
0x01ec, 117,1,"MFC-9640CW",133,4

0x020d ,17,1,"MFC-9450CDN",133,4
0x020c ,17,2,"DCP-9042CDN",133,4

-----------------------------
/usr/local/Brother/sane/models3/ext4.ini:
[Support Model]

0x0257,13,2,"DCP-J715W"
0x025d,13,1,"MFC-J615W"

0x0254,14,2,"DCP-J315W"
0x025B,14,1,"MFC-J265W"
0x026B,13,1,"MFC-J630W"
-----------------------------
MODEL:"DCP-197C",ID:0x4f9:0x23e,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-377CW",ID:0x4f9:0x235,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-257CW",ID:0x4f9:0x23a,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-195C",ID:0x4f9:0x222,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-365CN",ID:0x4f9:0x223,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-375CW",ID:0x4f9:0x224,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-395CN",ID:0x4f9:0x225,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-295CN",ID:0x4f9:0x229,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-495CW",ID:0x4f9:0x22a,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-795CW",ID:0x4f9:0x22c,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-255CW",ID:0x4f9:0x228,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-390CN",ID:0x4f9:0x236,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-595CN",ID:0x4f9:0x227,TYPE:13,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-495CN",ID:0x4f9:0x22b,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-675CD",ID:0x4f9:0x22d,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-695CDN",ID:0x4f9:0x22e,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-735CD",ID:0x4f9:0x22f,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-935CDN",ID:0x4f9:0x230,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-8070D",ID:0x4f9:0x21b,TYPE:17,2,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-8370DN",ID:0x4f9:0x21a,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-8380DN",ID:0x4f9:0x219,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-8680DN",ID:0x4f9:0x23f,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-8880DN",ID:0x4f9:0x216,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9120CN",ID:0x4f9:0x21d,TYPE:17,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9320CW",ID:0x4f9:0x21c,TYPE:17,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9010CN",ID:0x4f9:0x220,TYPE:17,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-9010CN",ID:0x4f9:0x21e,TYPE:17,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-J715N",ID:0x4f9:0x258,TYPE:13,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J615N",ID:0x4f9:0x25e,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-J515N",ID:0x4f9:0x256,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J950DN",ID:0x4f9:0x240,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J700D",ID:0x4f9:0x25f,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J800D",ID:0x4f9:0x260,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J850DN",ID:0x4f9:0x261,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J410W",ID:0x4f9:0x278,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J270W",ID:0x4f9:0x26f,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J855DN",ID:0x4f9:0x26e,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J805D",ID:0x4f9:0x26d,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-373CW",ID:0x4f9:0x234,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-253CW",ID:0x4f9:0x239,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-J125",ID:0x4f9:0x253,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-J515W",ID:0x4f9:0x255,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J220",ID:0x4f9:0x259,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J410",ID:0x4f9:0x25a,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J415W",ID:0x4f9:0x25c,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-5895CW",ID:0x4f9:0x276,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-9040CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1c9,TYPE:17,2,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9440CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1ca,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-9045CDN",ID:0x4f9:0x1cb,TYPE:17,2,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9840CDW",ID:0x4f9:0x1cc,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9640CW",ID:0x4f9:0x1ec,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-9450CDN",ID:0x4f9:0x20d,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-9042CDN",ID:0x4f9:0x20c,TYPE:17,2,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-J715W",ID:0x4f9:0x257,TYPE:13,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J615W",ID:0x4f9:0x25d,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-J315W",ID:0x4f9:0x254,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J265W",ID:0x4f9:0x25b,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-J630W",ID:0x4f9:0x26b,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-145C",ID:0x4f9:0x206,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-165C",ID:0x4f9:0x204,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-185C",ID:0x4f9:0x205,TYPE:13,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-385C",ID:0x4f9:0x201,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-585CW",ID:0x4f9:0x200,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-535CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1ff,TYPE:13,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-250C",ID:0x4f9:0x1fe,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-290C",ID:0x4f9:0x1fd,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-490CW",ID:0x4f9:0x1fb,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-490CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1fa,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-790CW",ID:0x4f9:0x1f9,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-990CW",ID:0x4f9:0x1f8,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-670CD",ID:0x4f9:0x1f7,TYPE:14,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-930CDN",ID:0x4f9:0x1f6,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-5490CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1f5,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-5890CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1f4,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-6690CW",ID:0x4f9:0x1f1,TYPE:13,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-6490CW",ID:0x4f9:0x1f3,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-6490CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1f2,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-6890CDW",ID:0x4f9:0x1f0,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-6890CN",ID:0x4f9:0x1ef,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-163C",ID:0x4f9:0x207,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-167C",ID:0x4f9:0x208,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-383C",ID:0x4f9:0x203,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-387C",ID:0x4f9:0x202,TYPE:14,2,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-297C",ID:0x4f9:0x1fc,TYPE:13,1,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-7450",ID:0x4f9:0x1ee,TYPE:1,1,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-7840N",ID:0x4f9:0x1ed,TYPE:1,1,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-7320",ID:0x4f9:0x1eb,TYPE:1,1,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-7030",ID:0x4f9:0x1ea,TYPE:2,2,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-7040",ID:0x4f9:0x1e9,TYPE:1,2,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-7045N",ID:0x4f9:0x1e8,TYPE:1,2,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-7340",ID:0x4f9:0x1e7,TYPE:1,1,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-7440N",ID:0x4f9:0x1e6,TYPE:1,1,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-7840W",ID:0x4f9:0x1e5,TYPE:1,1,RE:0x83,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:,ID:0x4f9:0xffff,TYPE:35,65535,RE:0xffff,WE:0xffff CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-8080DN",ID:0x4f9:0x218,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"DCP-8085DN",ID:0x4f9:0x21f,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-8480DN",ID:0x4f9:0x217,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
MODEL:"MFC-8890DW",ID:0x4f9:0x215,TYPE:17,1,RE:0x85,WE:0x4 CM:,,
-----------------------------
  0 "DCP-197C"
  1 "DCP-377CW"
  2 "MFC-257CW"
  3 "DCP-195C"
  4 "DCP-365CN"
  5 "DCP-375CW"
  6 "DCP-395CN"
  7 "MFC-295CN"
  8 "MFC-495CW"
  9 "MFC-795CW"
 10 "MFC-255CW"
 11 "DCP-390CN"
 12 "DCP-595CN"
 13 "MFC-495CN"
 14 "MFC-675CD"
 15 "MFC-695CDN"
 16 "MFC-735CD"
 17 "MFC-935CDN"
 18 "DCP-8070D"
 19 "MFC-8370DN"
 20 "MFC-8380DN"
 21 "MFC-8680DN"
 22 "MFC-8880DN"
 23 "MFC-9120CN"
 24 "MFC-9320CW"
 25 "MFC-9010CN"
 26 "DCP-9010CN"
 27 "DCP-J715N"
 28 "MFC-J615N"
 29 "DCP-J515N"
 30 "MFC-J950DN"
 31 "MFC-J700D"
 32 "MFC-J800D"
 33 "MFC-J850DN"
 34 "MFC-J410W"
 35 "MFC-J270W"
 36 "MFC-J855DN"
 37 "MFC-J805D"
 38 "DCP-373CW"
 39 "MFC-253CW"
 40 "DCP-J125"
 41 "DCP-J515W"
 42 "MFC-J220"
 43 "MFC-J410"
 44 "MFC-J415W"
 45 "MFC-5895CW"
 46 "DCP-9040CN"
 47 "MFC-9440CN"
 48 "DCP-9045CDN"
 49 "MFC-9840CDW"
 50 "MFC-9640CW"
 51 "MFC-9450CDN"
 52 "DCP-9042CDN"
 53 "DCP-J715W"
 54 "MFC-J615W"
 55 "DCP-J315W"
 56 "MFC-J265W"
 57 "MFC-J630W"
 58 "DCP-145C"
 59 "DCP-165C"
 60 "DCP-185C"
 61 "DCP-385C"
 62 "DCP-585CW"
 63 "DCP-535CN"
 64 "MFC-250C"
 65 "MFC-290C"
 66 "MFC-490CW"
 67 "MFC-490CN"
 68 "MFC-790CW"
 69 "MFC-990CW"
 70 "MFC-670CD"
 71 "MFC-930CDN"
 72 "MFC-5490CN"
 73 "MFC-5890CN"
 74 "DCP-6690CW"
 75 "MFC-6490CW"
 76 "MFC-6490CN"
 77 "MFC-6890CDW"
 78 "MFC-6890CN"
 79 "DCP-163C"
 80 "DCP-167C"
 81 "DCP-383C"
 82 "DCP-387C"
 83 "MFC-297C"
 84 "MFC-7450"
 85 "MFC-7840N"
 86 "MFC-7320"
 87 "DCP-7030"
 88 "DCP-7040"
 89 "DCP-7045N"
 90 "MFC-7340"
 91 "MFC-7440N"
 92 "MFC-7840W"
 93 
 94 "DCP-8080DN"
 95 "DCP-8085DN"
 96 "MFC-8480DN"
 97 "MFC-8890DW"

Devices on network
ping
```

Lastly, doing a

```
$ scanimage -L
```

Results to

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be helpful but have you seen [this support page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all&os=128) from Brother? It purports to have Linux drivers.

Comment: yes I have. got my installation files there....